# What does this mean ~method( ){ }

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the tilde (~) mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188688/what-does-the-tilde-mean-in-c)

What is the meaing of ~ before a method?

I saw this like here:

```
    ~myDirect3dClass() 
    { 

    }
```

Comment: It is a destructor used to relase the resources occupy by the object in C#.Net.

Comment: @waqar important point; it does ***not*** release resources occupied by the object (that is the job of GC); it allows the class to release any *unmanaged* resources that it may know about.

Comment: yup, you are right. Thanks Marc. MSDN Link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the [destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) of a class, aka. the Finalizer.

Answer (score 2):

That is a [destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

That is a [`Destructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b%28VS.80%29.aspx) method of a class.  Destructors are used to destruct instances of classes.

Comment: @Dave: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx