# What does the tilde do in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the tilde before a function name mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188688/what-does-the-tilde-mean-in-c)
>   [What is the tilde (~) in the enum definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387424/what-is-the-tilde-in-a-c-sharp-enumeration)

I know "~" is for Finalzier methods but now I saw some C# code like this:

```
if (~IsFieldDeleted(oRptField.GetLayoutField()) != 0)
{
   oCollection.Add(oRptField, oRptField.ObjectKeyString);
   // some more stuff
}
```

notice that "~" in the first line?

and then if I go to implementation of IsFieldDeleted it is a method that returns an int.

```
private int IsFieldDeleted(LayoutLib.LayoutField oLayoutField)
{
    Collection oColl = GetFieldIdsForField(oLayoutField);

    return (oColl.Count == 0) ? 1 : 0;

}
```

Comment: You could have googled this quite easily; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: If it's bitwise negation, then neither `~0` nor `~1` is zero.

Comment: i think it's bitwise negation.  kinda like `!` except for each bit in a value.

Answer (score 2):

The `~` operator performs a bitwise complement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-complement-operator

`IsFieldDeleted()` returns an *int*, which is a type to which that operator can be applied (int, uint, long, ulong).  The bitwise complement is taken and then compared to zero.

I don't see how the `if(...)` can ever be true, since `IsFieldDeleted()` only returns 0 or 1 and ~0 and ~1 are both not zero.

Comment: `IsFieldDeleted` returns either `0` or `1`. Their complement is never zero. Perhaps this is a bug in the original code?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Funny I was updating my post as you typed the comment.  Agree 100%.

Comment: @EricJ. : Thanks for inmfo but when I put a break point inside the commands of that if(...) block it hits the break point.

Comment: @user1899082: Try assigning the return value of `IsFieldDeleted()` to an int variable and share what that value is.

Comment: @EricJ. IsFieldDeleted was zero so its negate was negative one so it went inside the if block .