# What is a function that has a ~ before the function declaration?

Tags: c#

So i bumped in to this:

```
Public Stam {
       public Stam() {Console.WriteLine("Stam");}

       ~Stam(){Console.WriteLine("Stam")}
       }
```

What exactly is the ~? and what will happen when i call the Stam class.

Comment: Finalizer. And you don't call classes.

Comment: @ta.speot.is When i mean call class i meant referring to the class or having the initialize do something

Comment: It's a finalizer/destructor. If one occurs in your code, you almost certainly did something wrong.

Comment: is this what you are looking for?
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188688/what-does-the-tilde-mean-in-c)

Comment: Destructors in C# are denoted with ~ oeprator.

Comment: Please see this answer by one of the guys who has worked on the development of C#: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4899622/2920343. Especially note the first two words ("When should I use a destructor?"): "Almost never" followed by a bunch of warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [~ operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx), in this circumstance, is being used to denote the class destructor, [destructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) are called automatically as part of the cleanup process.

However, the `~` can also be used for bitwise complement operation.

Answer (score 0):

It is a destructor for the class. It is called automatically when an instance of the class is deleted, you use it to delete objects etc.

Answer (score 0):

In C# it's called [Destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx), the equivalent to a C++ destructor is `IDisposable` and the `Dispose()` method, often used in a using block.

See [System.IDisposable from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx)

What you are calling a destructor is better known as a `Finalizer.`

Answer (score 0):

generally [destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) function/methods are declared like this.

Your call seems like a [finalizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).