# What does ~ do?

Tags: c#

This [post](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/10/construction-destruction/#more-1203) contains the following source code:

```
class Foo 
{ 
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public Foo(int x, int y) 
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        SideEffects.Alpha(); // Notice: does not use "this"
    }
    ~Foo() 
    { 
        SideEffects.Charlie(); 
    }
}
static class SideEffects
{
    public static void Alpha() { ... }
    public static void Bravo() { ... }
    public static void Charlie() { ... }
    public static void M()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo(1, 2); 
        Bravo();
    }
}
```

What does `~` do?

Comment: It specifies a class destructor. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It is used for [Destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) in C# which implicitly calls Finalize method.

> Destructors are used to destruct instances of classes.
>
> The destructor implicitly calls Finalize on the base class of the
>   object.
>
> The programmer has no control over when the destructor is called
>   because this is determined by the garbage collector. The garbage
>   collector checks for objects that are no longer being used by the
>   application. If it considers an object eligible for destruction, it
>   calls the destructor (if any) and reclaims the memory used to store
>   the object. Destructors are also called when the program exits.

Comment: @Downvoter, care to comment ?

Comment: I think the question shows little research effort, should be closed as a dupe, and deleted. Your answer is correct and helpful, but it does not add anything significant to [the other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188688/what-does-the-tilde-mean-in-c), instead it just keeps this question from being deleted. Obviously, I mean no offense to you or the asker, I just don't think we as a community should answer questions that already have easy to find duplicates (googling "c# tilde method" takes you to the correct page), and instead should just politely point to the duplicate.

Comment: @Gray, downvoting on answer of duplicate question is [debatable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions). But thanks for the clarification, I was just concerned if my answer is wrong technically. Thanks

Comment: That was a helpful discussion; thank you for the link. I guess I would say that this question teeters the line of being an egregious duplicate just because I would be very surprised to find a question like "what does the ___ operator do?" to not already have an answer. It just seems too basic. Someone made a good point about not punishing the answerer for the OP's mistake, but I feel like I want to encourage super helpful people like yourself to spend time on questions without an answer. Either way, I'd undo my downvote at this point if I could just because the link made me question my ideals.

Comment: @Gray, Google returns strange results if search for "C# ~ operator", for a guy like me who has English as third language, It is sometimes difficult to search for the exact term like "tilde". Anyway, I have voted to close the question and delete as well :)

Answer (score 1):

It is the symbol for the C# [Destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx). There's a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188688/what-does-the-tilde-mean-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

The ~ symbol also is used to declare destructors says the [~ Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx)